# .NET Show data from database based on day

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am currently developing a reservation system for vehicles and the user is able to pick a car from a dropdown list but some cars can't be used on specific days (e.g. Monday). Is there a way to exclude cars based on the day?

**EDIT**

Added the code for the reservation function before choosing a vehicle

```
       public ActionResult ReserveInitial()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReserveInitial(ReservationViewModel RVM)
    {
        var repo = new ManagementRepository();
        var resini = new ReservedVehicleDetail
        {
            Id = RVM.Id,
            BorrowerLastName = RVM.BorrowerLastName,
            BorrowerFirstName = RVM.BorrowerFirstName,
            VehicleID = RVM.VehicleID,
            Reason = RVM.Reason,
            ProjectID = RVM.ProjectID,
            Location = RVM.Location,
            DateTimeStart = RVM.DateTimeStart,
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
            UserID = RVM.UserID,
            DriverID = RVM.DriverID,
            IsActive = false

        };



        repo.ReserveInitial(resini);
        //TempData["ID"] = resini.Id;
        //TempData.Keep();
        return RedirectToAction("ChooseVehicle", "Reservation", new { id = resini.Id });
    }
```

Here's my code for the selecting a car:

```
       public ActionResult ChooseVehicle(int? id)
    {


        // int id = (int)TempData["ID"];

        ReservedVehicleDetail resDet = db.ReservedVehicleDetails.Find(id);
        var RVM = new ReservationViewModel();
        ViewBag.VehicleID = db.Vehicles.Select(a => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = a.VehicleID.ToString(),
            Text = a.VehicleMake + " - " + a.PlateNumber
        });
        //   ViewBag.VehicleID = new SelectList(db.Vehicles, "VehicleID", "VehicleMake");

        RVM.Id = resDet.Id;
        RVM.BorrowerLastName = resDet.BorrowerLastName;
        RVM.BorrowerFirstName = resDet.BorrowerFirstName;
        RVM.Reason = resDet.Reason;
        RVM.ProjectID = resDet.ProjectID;
        RVM.Location = resDet.Location;
        RVM.DateTimeStart = resDet.DateTimeStart;
        RVM.DateCreated = resDet.DateCreated;
        RVM.UserID = resDet.UserID;
        RVM.IsActive = resDet.IsActive;
        //RVM.DriverID = resIni.DriverID;


        TempData.Keep();
        return View(RVM);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChooseVehicle(ReservationViewModel RVM)
    {
        var repo = new ManagementRepository();
        var resDet = new ReservedVehicleDetail();
        //        int id = (int)TempData["ID"];


        using (var db = new VehicleReservationEntities())
        {
            var existingReservation = (from data in db.ReservedVehicleDetails
                                       where data.Id == RVM.Id
                                       select data).FirstOrDefault();
            existingReservation.Id = RVM.Id;
            existingReservation.BorrowerLastName = RVM.BorrowerLastName;
            existingReservation.BorrowerFirstName = RVM.BorrowerFirstName;
            existingReservation.VehicleID = RVM.VehicleID;
            existingReservation.Reason = RVM.Reason;
            existingReservation.ProjectID = RVM.ProjectID;
            existingReservation.Location = RVM.Location;
            existingReservation.DateTimeStart = RVM.DateTimeStart;
            existingReservation.DateCreated = RVM.DateCreated;
            existingReservation.UserID = RVM.UserID;
            existingReservation.IsActive = false;
            //existingVehicle.DriverID = RVM.DriverID;

            repo.chooseVehicle(existingReservation);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("DriverCheck", "Reservation", new { id = RVM.Id });
    }
```

Comment: Please see my answer, feel free to ask any questions.  If that answers you question please Upvote and Mark as Resolved

Comment: @johnny5 hi! I'll give this a try once I go through the function again, I'll give you an update, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**To Answer your Question:** 
Yes It's a bit confusing to do in SQL but I'll explain how.
You want to Filter out mondays, so you just get the date different from a day that starts on sunday

e.g Sunday January 7, 1900, 
Since Sunday is the beginning of the week (index 0), if you modulo a the date you want you can create a filter from that.

```
DayOfWeek d = DayOfWeek.Monday;

var vehicles = db.ReservedVehicleDetails.Where(x =>
    DbFunctions.DiffDays(new DateTime(1900, 1, 7), x.someDateField) % 7 != (int)d);
```

(Just replace someDateField, with the field the contains the date which is reserved.)

**To Fix Your Problem**
You probably don't want to be doing that in general, my guess is you need to change your architecture so you can just get the available vehicles by checking the request time doesn't overlap the reservation time.

```
db.Vechicles.Where(x => !x.Reservation.Any(r => r.StartDate <= requestedEndDate
                                             && requestedStartDate <= x.EndDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ChooseVehicle` GET action is what displays your list of available vehicles for selection by `ViewBag.VehicleID`, but it's not clear which date/dates are being requested by the user just yet.  Knowing which dates are Mondays, for example, and displaying only appropriate vehicles for selection first is what I'd think about next.  There also might be some difficulties with your requirements.  What would happen with a vehicle request that spans a whole week but Mondays are not allowed?

Not part of your question, but I'd also consider moving your ORM queries out of your controller actions and into a service layer class or two.  It will save you time and trouble later by enabling you to more easily reuse your own code.

Once you have the information necessary to filter to the desired results you could efficiently do so with your database query so you don't have to fetch records from your database map entity instances into your C# just to decide to exclude them.

In T-SQL look at using the `DATEPART(dw, DateField)` function which gives you a number 1-7 for the day of week to only fetch logically selectable vehicles for presentation.

Comment: I edited my post and added the reservation function itself. Reservations are only to last a day sorry if I didn't mention it. Thank you for your input!